# UIButton Text disappears after click

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a Button with a background1 and titled "1", and I use `NSUserDefaults` to change the background when the button is clicked to background2.

It does what I want, but the title disappears after the click.. Is that normal or i should do something else?

I use this to set the title:

```
[self.One  setTitle:@"1" forState:0];
```

And I tried `forState:UIControlStateNormal];` and so on but didn't work.

Comment: What code are you using to change the background?

Comment: You should change the backgroundImage, not the image. I think your image is over your title.

Comment: @incmiko Yeah, that's what I'm thinking... But we can help you confirm that OP if you post the code you're using to change the background.